# Append an ActiveRecord::Relation object with single ActiveRecord object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I need to append a single ActiveRecord object onto a loaded ActiveRecord::Relation.

E.g:

```rb
class BooksController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @books = Book.where(author: User.find(params[:user_id]))
    @books << Book.find_by_name("One More Book")
  end
end
```

As shown above, I have tried [ActiveRecord's `<<` method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/CollectionProxy.html#method-i-3C-3C), but it returns the error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `<<' for #<Book::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007f9fbdc6db80>
```

Is there an elegant way of doing this?

Thanks!

Comment: why don't you use an `or` in one single query ?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a *temporary* fix, I have done the following:

```rb
books = Book.where(author: User.find(params[:user_id])).pluck(:id)
books << Book.find_by_name("One More Book").id
@books = Book.where(id: books)
```

For obvious reasons, this is solution is far from ideal, but it does work while a better solution can be found.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `or` method introduced in Rails 5, although this only works with `where` (which returns an ActiveRecord::Relation object) and not with `find_by_name` (as it returns a Book object).

```
Book.where(author_id: params[:user_id])).or(Book.where(name: "One More Book"))
```

If the relationship is well defined this should also work:

```
Book.where(author: params[:user_id])).or(Book.where(name: "One More Book"))
```

Note that `where` could return more than one object. Using `where` + `limit` in an `or` is also not allowed.

If you want to append a single object, you can do it by plucking the ids, but this raises 3 queries instead of 1:

```
users_array = User.where(author: params[:user_id]) | [Book.find_by_name("One More Book")]
Book.where(id: users_array)
```

Alternatively, depending what you are doing afterwards, having the result in an array may be enough:

```
Book.where(author_id: params[:user_id])) | [Book.find_by_name("One More Book")]
```

Note the use of `|` (union), as I assume you don't want duplicates. Otherwise you can use `+`, but this only makes a different for the array and not for an ActiveRecord::Relation (there are no duplicates).

Answer (score 0):

Since this is rails 5 you can use the `or` method

```
Books.where(author: User.find(params[:user_id])).or.where(name: "One More Book")
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. This looks good, although i receive the error: `ArgumentError: Relation passed to #or must be structurally compatible. Incompatible values: [:joins]`. Any ideas? Thanks again!

Comment: what is the model association between book and author? does books, have a foreign key author_id?

Comment: This seems to be a bug that was already fixed: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/24055

Comment: but you don't need an extra query to look for the author, I have posted an improved version of this answer :)